# Assume $g: A \to B$ and $f: B \to C$. If $f\circ g$ is surjective, then $f$ would be injective. True or false?

Tags: functions, relations

Assume $g: A \to B$ and $f: B \to C$.

If $f\circ g$ is surjective, then $f$ would be injective. Would this proposition be true or false?

Comment: It's false.  Just think about it.

Comment: Think about the case where $A=B$ and $g(x)=x$ for all $x\in A$. Then, your statement becomes "if $f:A\to C$ is surjective, then $f$ is injective", which is obviously not true in general.

Answer (score -1):

If $f \circ g$ is surjective, you can only say that $f$ must be surjective (otherwise there exists $c \in C$ such that $c \notin f(B)$, thus $c \notin f(g(A))$).

Let $A, B \ne \emptyset$ and $C$ be a set with a single element. Then we always have $g \circ f$ surjective, but we do not know anything about $f$ except that it is surjective.

However, if $f \circ g$ is injective, then $g$ must be injective. In fact, let $g(x) = g(y)$. Then $f(g(x)) = f(g(y))$ which shows that $x =  y$.